# Deploying Django application as Wordpress subpage (at sub url), mod-wsgi

Tags: apache-2.2, wordpress, django, mod-wsgi

I have a Wordpress blog, let's say that it's address is like `yakblog.org` and it is a Wordpress blog installed on Ubuntu 12.04 server.

Now, I would like to run a Django application as one of the sub page of my blog, so I could access it like this: `yakblog.org/testproject`.

Here's the EXACT situation: https://community.webfaction.com/questions/17758/wordpress-on-root-domain-django-in-subdirectory (although I don't use webfaction). Also, I tried the solution given here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26013379/run-django-project-inside-wordpress-on-suburl-of-wordpress-using-apache-and-mod, but then I have a Wordpress message: `This is somewhat embarrassing, isn’t it?`

However, I encountered some problems doing this, and I'm not sure if it's possible with my set up. Ok, so here's what I did to achieve what I need:

1. Created a Django project at `/var/www/yak/public_html`, so in `/var/www/yak/public_html` I have such structure:

[image]

2. Then, added a line `WSGIPythonPath /var/www/yak/public_html/testproject` to my `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` file
3. Here's my virtual host code:

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
       ServerName  yakblog.org/testproject 
       ServerAlias www.yakblog.org/testproject 

   #RedirectPermanent / http://yakblog.org/testproject

   WSGIScriptAlias /testproject /var/www/yak/public_html/testproject/testproject/wsgi.py

   DocumentRoot /var/www/yak/public_html/testproject/

   <Directory />
           Options FollowSymLinks
           AllowOverride None
   </Directory>

   <Directory /var/www/yak/public_html/testproject/>
           Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
           AllowOverride All
           Order allow,deny
           allow from all
   </Directory>

   ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
   <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
           AllowOverride None
           Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
           Order allow,deny
           Allow from all
   </Directory>

   ErrorLog /home/yak/logs/error.log

   # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
   # alert, emerg.
   LogLevel warn

   CustomLog /home/yak/logs/access.log combined

   Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
   <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
   Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride None
   Order deny,allow
   Deny from all
   Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
   </Directory>

   </VirtualHost>
   ```

The problem is when entering `http://yakblog.org/testproject` I can't see my application, but only the list of files in this directory:

[image]

Comment: Likely that VirtualHost isn't used. It should be within the same VirtualHost as your Wordpress application is setup. BTW. That you can see the code shows why you should NEVER put your Django project code under DocumentRoot directory. It should go somewhere else. Also use daemon mode of mod_wsgi and not embedded mode. http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2012/10/why-are-you-using-embedded-mode-of.html

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here

`<Directory /var/www/yak/public_html/testproject/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
</Directory>`

You are showing the content of the folder, not running the actual application.

You can look the documentation to setup your server https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/

What you need to do is install mod_wsgi and add this to

```
<Directory /path/to/mysite.com/mysite>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
```

Where you only serve wsgi.py and wsgi.py it's used to serve your application.